# How to "Import" a *.SQL File

Tags: sql, database, import, hosting

I am hosted on Winhost.com.  They support both PHP and ASP.NET. I have a PHP User Management script and the instructions are as follows:

- Step 1 : Login to your web hosting account and create a database and inport the database.sql file.
- Step 2: Open config.php with notepad and change the settings to your database details.
- Step 3: Upload all the files to your web server.

The propblem I am having is that I have successfully created a database in my control panel on @WinHost, BUT There is no option that lets me "import" the *.sql file that is mentioned in Step 1.

Does anybody know how I can get around this/import it?

I have searched all over Winhost support pages and can't find any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "run query" interface, take the text from database.sql and put them in there, then click "execute query".  Or similar language, I don't know what Winhost does.

Comment: Thank you. WinHost does not have a Run Query interface. However, I just found out that they do allow you to "publish/import" sql databases into it via Web Developer (VS). BUT I don't know if it will work as I am dealing with PHP this time, not asp.net. :(

Comment: SQL is SQL.  It's neither PHP nor ASP.

Comment: True. But you don't develop websites in Visual Web Developer using anything other than ASP/ASP.NET (afaik). So why would a web host supporting multiple languages REQUIRE you to use a program that only supports ASP.NET to import a sql file? That just doesn't make any sense. Do they really expect people who don't use asp/asp.net to download/install a 200-odd mb program just so they can import a 15kb file? There has to be a better way

Answer (score 1):

The [How to migrate from your local SQL 2005 database to a WinHost SQL 2008 database](http://support.winhost.com/KB/a699/how-to-migrate-from-your-local-sql-2005-database-to.aspx) page has a section titled *Running the SQL script against our SQL 2008 servers*.  I think that may be what you are after.  It explains how you can log in to the control panel, open a command prompt, and run `sqlcmd` to import a SQL script.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I am checking this out now. :)